# I'm having trouble with this in solidity in withdrawmoney() function

Tags: solidity

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract sendMoney {
    
    uint public balanceRecieved;
    
    function recieveMoney()public payable {
        balanceRecieved += msg.value;
    }
    
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function withdrawMoney() public {
        to payable(msg.sender)   = address;
        to.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'payable' --> browser/sendMoney.sol:16:12: | 16 | to payable(msg.sender) = address; | ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect on this line:

```
to payable(msg.sender)   = address;
```

Correct syntax:

```
address payable to = payable(msg.sender);
```